# Can't find .erlang.cookie file

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have installed ejabberd-18.09 on mac through binary installation. But I am not able to find the `.erlang.cookie file`. Ejabberd is working fine, but is there any command to get the path of the cookie file. If not, where can I find it?

**EDIT**

Although I can't find the .erlang.cookie file anywhere in the system but after starting the ejabberd in live mode I get erlang:get_cookie() as a cookie.

I am actually stumped here about how can I change this cookie from it's current value to something else as there is no flag as `-setCookie AWSXEDCRFVGBGHT` anywhere in the ejabberdctl file.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440847/113848), the cookie is in `/var/lib/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie` - not sure if that's still the case.

Comment: thanks for the reply @legoscia, but mine `/var/lib/ejabberd ` does not have any erlang.cookie file. I even have installed ejabberd-18.09 on Linux os as well but the erlang.cookie file is not available there as well. Any more pointers if possible please.

Comment: I am going to try and edit the ejabberdctl file now.